# Pyspark pyspark.sql.functions acting weird

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate, apache-spark-sql

The "last" function under pyspark.sql.functions is returning inconsistency results on spark when we have more than 3 nodes to distribute the data.

Here are the codes that can easily regenerate the issue.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

numeric = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('purple', '5.0', '20'), ('blue', '2.6', '19'),  
('purple', '3.8', '15'),('purple', '3', '12'),  ('purple', '2', '4.0'), ('blue', '2', '4.0'),
('purple', '10', '11'),  ('purple', '2.5', '4.8'), 
('blue', '2.3', '4.9')],('color', 'v1', 'v2')) 
numeric.printSchema()

numeric = numeric.withColumn("v1t", numeric["v1"].cast(DoubleType()))
numeric.printSchema()

sort_numeric = numeric.sort('v1t', ascending=True)
last_by_color = sort_numeric.groupBy("color").agg(F.last("v1").alias("last_v1"), F.last("v2").alias("last_v2"))
```

Each time the "last_by_color.show()" will give you different results.
Here are the terminal output when I tested this on --master yarn-client (local is always fine)

Please see attached image.

[Terminal_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpI1J.png)

Comment: I am using spark 2.0.0, --master yarn --deploy-mode client

Answer (score 0):

`pyspark.sql.functions.first` and `pyspark.sql.functions.last` function is non-deterministic because its results depends on order of rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.

Pyspark documentations [pyspark.sql.functions.last](http://%20https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.last)

The recommended way to use first and last is with window finction.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy("<your_key_column>").orderBy('<your_order_by_column>')
```

in your case while defining window partition by column would be "color". Order by columns are generally dates/timestamps and we have option to sort the data both ways acsending and descending. You don't have a date column to sort the data.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import last

numeric.withColumn("v1_last", last('v1').over(w))\
       .withColumn("v2_last", last('v2').over(w))\
.show()
```

Above will give `numeric` dataframe with additional 'last_v1' and 'last_v2' columns. So you need to reduce it to one record per group/partition.